# How do I access Personas theme data on addons.mozilla.org

Tags: firefox-addon, mozilla

addons.mozilla.org comes with an XML API that you could fetch any public data from it's database:

For example, information about this Personas:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/this-blue-planet/

can be accessed as XML:

https://services.addons.mozilla.org/zh-TW/firefox/api/1.5/addon/this-blue-planet

The only problem is, unlike extensions, where the URL of XPI and the file hash is all you need to initiate an off-site install, Personas is represented as a JSON object in `data-browsertheme` property of the `mouseover`-able and `click`-able preview button; the content of JSON object cannot be found within the XML representation.

I've think of fetch the HTML page and parse the content, but I need a robust method that doesn't break with an AMO version update. Anyone can answer my question or point me a person that could answer the question is greatly appreciated.

PS: I am making a Firefox promotion website that work with these data, if you are interested you could check it out (in Traditional Chinese): http://gfx.tw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addons.mozilla.org API doesn't currently support Personas. The primary home of Personas is getpersonas.com, and it doesn't have an API.

You can file a bug for Persona support at bugzilla.mozilla.org, but it likely won't be integrated until much later in the year.

Comment: Thanks. Are you coming from AMO team?

Comment: I'll take your answer since there is no other one.

Comment: Yes, I'm the Product Manager for add-ons